# How to uncover drive status with Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, ntfs

With
Ubuntu 20.04.4
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

In a bash script, how to state a directory
like (/home/u3/Music/x) and get:

- Partition Type and
- File system
  for that drive
  for above directory posted to the screen?

A directory is supplied in a script that compare 2 directories.
Here are 4 example directories:

src1='/media/u3/F_4GB_FAT32'      # usb drive F 4GBytes Fat32 filesystem
src1='/media/u3/s_931GBNmbr/1'    # Sata HDD drive 931 GB, Ntfs filesystem, master boot record
src1='/media/u3/u7451GBGPTn/z1'   # usb 7451GB = 8TB, GPT Partition, Ntfs filesystem
src1='/home/u3/Music/x'           # SDD ubuntu drive

src1 is a source directory versus
dest is a destination directory

Some success with this:

```
lsblk -o pttype,mountpoint,LABEL,TRAN,SIZE,FSUSE%,fstype,kname,path | head -n1 ;  
lsblk -o pttype,mountpoint,LABEL,TRAN,SIZE,FSUSE%,fstype,kname,path | grep '/media/u3/s_931GBmbrN' ;
```

Giving:

```
PTTYPE MOUNTPOINT                   LABEL       TRAN     SIZE FSUSE% FSTYPE   KNAME  PATH
dos    /media/u3/s_931GBmbrN        s_931GBmbrN        931.5G    46% ntfs     sdc1   /dev/sdc1
```

dos = mbr = MBR = Master Boot Record Partition Type and
ntfs = File system type, New Technology File System

but above command easily breaks,
when directory is something other like:
/home/u3/Music/x

because
grep '/home/u3/Music/x'
yeilds a blank, no result.

In a bash script, how to state a directory
like (/home/u3/Music/x) and get:

- Partition Type and
- Filesystem
  for that drive
  for above directory?

--

Answer (score 0):

With `findmnt`, depending on what you want:

```
findmnt -nfo FSTYPE -T /home/u3/Music/x
findmnt -nfo SOURCE -T /home/u3/Music/x
findmnt -nfo TARGET -T /home/u3/Music/x
findmnt -nfo FSTYPE,SOURCE,TARGET -T /home/u3/Music/x
```

You can get more information from `findmnt`. Read `man 8 findmnt` and `findmnt --help`.

Some information you can get from `stat`:

```
stat -fc %T /home/u3/Music/x
stat -c %m /home/u3/Music/x
```

See `man 1 stat` for details.

---

Example:

```sh
file=/home/u3/Music/x
device="$(findmnt -nvfo SOURCE -T "$file")"

# information obtained, now we can use it

[ "$device" ] && lsblk "$device"
[ "$device" ] && df -h "$device"
[ "$device" ] && sudo file -s "$device"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer ...
bash script example of desired output for:

- Partition Type and
- File system
  for directory

```
/home/u3/Music/x
```

using Kamil's answer:

```
file=/home/u3/Music/x ; device="$(findmnt -nvfo SOURCE -T "$file")" ;
```

Short script:

```
[ "$device" ] && lsblk -o PTTYPE,FSTYPE "$device" ; echo "$file" ;
```

screen answer:

```
PTTYPE FSTYPE
dos    ext4
/home/u3/Music/x
```

Longer script:

```
[ "$device" ] && lsblk -o PTTYPE,FSTYPE,PATH,NAME,MODEL,SIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSED,FSUSE%,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT "$device" ; echo "$file" ;
```

screen:

```
PTTYPE FSTYPE PATH      NAME MODEL   SIZE FSAVAIL FSUSED FSUSE% LABEL MOUNTPOINT
dos    ext4   /dev/sda5 sda5       111.3G   58.6G  44.9G    41%       /
/home/u3/Music/x
```

note, a conflicting result with

```
stat -fc %T /home/u3/Music/x
```

ext2/ext3

because this says file system is `ext4` not `ext2/ext3`

```
[ "$device" ] && lsblk -o FSTYPE "$device" ; echo "$file" ;
```

```
FSTYPE
ext4
/home/u3/Music/x
```

.

Post a new question? or leave it here?
8000GB = 8TB usb drive says:

```
file=/media/u3/u7451GBGPTn ; device="$(findmnt -nvfo SOURCE -T "$file")" ; [ "$device" ] && lsblk -o PTTYPE,FSTYPE "$device" ;
```

```
PTTYPE FSTYPE
atari  ntfs
```

Without an external source (web page) ...
How in a bash script can we clarify that
`atari` PTTYPE (Partition Type) means
`gpt`  ?
GPT  = Guid Partition Table,
Guid = Globally unique identifiers

--

Comment: `"In addition to above answer ..."`  Your answer is on top now - there is nothing above it :)  Maybe use a link to the answer you are referring to. Get that link by clicking `Share` below the answer & above the comments to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

using Kamil's answer ...

One line output for Partition Type status for directory `/home/u3/Music/x` :

`src1='/home/u3/Music/x' ; clear ; echo "   one line PTTYPE status (Partition Type): " ; tput sgr0 ; device="$(findmnt -nvfo SOURCE -T "$src1")" ; [ "$device" ] && lsblk -o PTTYPE "$device" | paste -sd ' ' | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf  12 ; echo "$src1" ;`

screen:

`PTTYPE dos /home/u3/Music/x`

and
One line output for File System status for directory `/home/u3/Music/x` :

`src1='/home/u3/Music/x' ; clear ; echo "   one line FSTYPE status (File System): " ; tput sgr0 ; device="$(findmnt -nvfo SOURCE -T "$src1")" ; [ "$device" ] && lsblk -o FSTYPE "$device" | paste -sd ' ' | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf  12 ; echo "$src1" ;`

screen:

`FSTYPE ext4 /home/u3/Music/x`

using paste command, merge 2 lines into 1 line
u3 = user3
src1=source directory, sending directory.

--

Comment: Is this a reply to Kamil, or a thank you, or something else? To comment, please use the comment section. To say thank you, mark the answer as correct. If this is something else please use the EDIT button to make the point more clear.