# How to show Device Path, Parent folder, file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

Using:
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)

With explorer on a file we have the
Ctrl-I = Properties command
Parent folder and file showing:

`/home/u3/Music/file.txt`

stat gives undesired output with:
`stat file.txt`

What is the Terminal command to show
Device Path, Parent folder, file?

Examples of desired output:

`/dev/nvme0n1p2/home/u3/Music/file.txt`

or

`/dev/sda5/home/u3/Music/file.txt`

--
Question from Kamil ;
What do you need such nonstandard structure for?

Answer:
Pinpoint file.txt location.

Ctril-I says
/home/u3/Music/file.txt

But
`lsblk -e7 -o PTTYPE,FSTYPE,PATH,SIZE`

```
PTTYPE FSTYPE PATH             SIZE  
dos           /dev/sda       931.5G  
dos    ntfs   /dev/sda1      931.5G  
dos           /dev/sdb       931.5G  
dos    ntfs   /dev/sdb1      931.5G  
gpt           /dev/sdc         7.3T  
gpt           /dev/sdc1        128M  
atari  ntfs   /dev/sdc2        7.3T  
       vfat   /dev/sdd         3.7G  
gpt           /dev/nvme0n1   465.8G  
gpt    vfat   /dev/nvme0n1p1   512M  
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p2 465.3G
```

In above eleven (11) Partitions / Devices ...
What Terminal command would Pinpoint file.txt location?

What Terminal command  would pinpoint
one of above eleven (11) for location of :
/home/u3/Music/file.txt  ?

--

Comment: You will not be getting that output from any tool because this is an _incorrect_ path that does not actually exist. You can build it yourself, however.

Comment: (1) Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. What do you need such nonstandard structure for? (2) If you want a "path" independent of current mounts then `/dev/sda5` is not enough information. Think about bind mounts or Btrfs subvolumes. (3) And `sda5` today may be `sdb5` tomorrow. (4) Suppose `/dev/sda5` is mounted on `/home`. Should `/home/u3/Music/file.txt` be translated to `/dev/sda5/u3/Music/file.txt` or to `/dev/sda5/home/u3/Music/file.txt`. IMO the former makes more sense because there is no `/home` in the filesystem on `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: (5) To mitigate ambiguity [consider using `//`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256497/108618), e.g.  `//dev:sda5/home/u3/Music/file.txt`. If you use this in a context where Linux expects a pathname, it will still interpret it as such (your original design is similarly "flawed"), but at least anyone who has a clue will suspect it's not a regular pathname. Another possibility to make it reasonably clear it's a custom format: `joseph22:///dev/sda5/home/u3/Music/file.txt`.

Comment: Question updated, see bottom of Question in response to Kamil.

Comment: `findmnt` ([you should know it](https://superuser.com/a/1723913/432690)) may be useful. Note if you want to store a "superpath" to a file and if you want to start with a block device, then in general you also need the offset (as in `mount -o offset=…`). You need the path inside the filesystem rather than the current path in the directory tree in the OS (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1396270/432690)). `/dev/disk/by-uuid` or so is better than `/dev/sda5`. And what if it's `/dev/loop5`? Then you need to pinpoint another file first (the file housing the filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

Question was:
How to show Device Path, Parent folder, file?

We have Parent folder, file:
`/home/u3/Music/file.txt`
but, where is `file.txt`?

What device is `file.txt` on?

using Kamil's answer ... we have:

```
clear ; file=/home/u3/Music/file.txt ; device="$(findmnt -nvfo SOURCE -T "$file")" ;  [ "$device" ] && lsblk -o PTTYPE,FSTYPE,PATH,NAME,MODEL,SIZE,FSAVAIL,FSUSED,FSUSE%,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT "$device" ; echo "$file" ;
```

Output:

```
PTTYPE FSTYPE PATH           NAME      MODEL   SIZE FSAVAIL FSUSED FSUSE% LABEL MOUNTPOINT    
gpt    ext4   /dev/nvme0n1p2 nvme0n1p2       465.3G  395.7G    38G     8%       /    
/home/u3/Music/file.txt
```

Answer:
Location of `/home/u3/Music/file.txt` is on `/dev/nvme0n1p2`

--

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, something like this:
we define new variable with path to file, using the **du** command - we determine the mount point, and using **awk** we make the output:

```
filez=/home/u3/Music/file.txt && df $filez | grep dev | awk -v var=$filez '{print $1 var}'
```

as a result, you should get what you are looking for:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2/home/u3/Music/file.txt
```